# Mocking async function jest to test transitive state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have a component that handles the login part of my app and I would like to test it's loading state.

Basically it does the following:

- press a button to login
- disable the button
- make the request
- enable back the button

What is the best way to mock `AuthStore.login` in this case to be able to test when `isLoading` is `true` and when it get back to `false` ?
I tried mocking with

```js
const loginSpy = jest.spyOn(AuthStore, 'login').mockResolvedValueOnce({ success: true })
```

but then it returns immediately and I'm not able to test when the button should be disabled.

Here is a sample of the code

```js
const Login = function(){

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

    async function onPressGoogleLogin() {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const {
            success,
            error
        } = await AuthStore.login()
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    return ...
}
```

My test using `@testing-library/react-native` looks like this.

```js
    it.only('testing login', async () => {
        const { getByA11yHint } = render(<LoginScreen componentId="id-1" />)
        const btn = getByA11yHint('login')
        expect(btn).not.toBeDisabled()
        await act(async () => {
            await fireEvent.press(btn)
        })
        expect(btn).toBeDisabled()
        expect(within(btn).getByTestId('loader')).toBeTruthy()
    })
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it to work in one test (with Jest 27)

```js
import { act, fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react-native'
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { Pressable } from 'react-native'

const Utils = {
    sleep: (ms: number) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    }
}

const Component = function () {
    const [refreshing, setRefresh] = useState(false)

    const refresh = useCallback(async () => {
        setRefresh(true)
        await Utils.sleep(5000)
        setRefresh(false)
    }, [])

    return <Pressable testID="btn" onPress={refresh} disabled={refreshing} />
}

const sleepSpy = jest.spyOn(Utils, 'sleep').mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        process.nextTick(resolve)
    })
})

describe('Test', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<Component />)
        const btn = getByTestId('btn')
        expect(btn.props.accessibilityState.disabled).toBeFalsy()
        let f = fireEvent.press(btn)
        expect(sleepSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
        expect(btn.props.accessibilityState.disabled).toBeTruthy()
        await act(async () => {
            await f
        })
        expect(btn.props.accessibilityState.disabled).toBeFalsy()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test 1**

Mock `AuthStore.login()` to not return a resolving promise. Mock it to return a pending promise. Inquire about the state of things when the button is pressed.

**Test 2**

Then, in a separate test, mock `AuthStore.login()` to return a resolving promise. Inquire about the state of things when the button is pressed.

**Test 3**

Bonus points: in a separate test, mock `AuthStore.login()` to return a *rejecting* promise. Inquire about the state of things when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you elaborate how you would mock the pending promise here ? Not sure on how to do it.
I tried with `const loginSpy = jest.spyOn(AuthStore, 'login').mockImplementation(async () => new Promise((resolve) => {}))` but it does not work